# Spring boot hibernate complex table relationship works partially

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have following models they have one-to-one and one-to-many and many-to-one relationship. Most of the model are fine except one.

My json data:

```
        {
            
                    "name": "Warehouse A",
                    "location": {
                    "lat": "47.13111",
                    "long": "-61.54801"
                    },
                    "cars": {
                    "location": "West wing",
                    "vehicles": [
                        {
                        "make": "Volkswagen",
                        "model": "Jetta III",
                        "year_model": 1995,
                        "price": 12947.52,
                        "licensed": true,
                        "date_added": "2018-09-18"
                        },
                        {

                        "make": "Chevrolet",
                        "model": "Corvette",
                        "year_model": 2004,
                        "price": 20019.64,
                        "licensed": true,
                        "date_added": "2018-01-27"
                        }
                    ]
                    }
    }
```

Java models:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouse")
public class Warehouse {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("location")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "warehouse", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Location location;
    @JsonProperty("cars")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "warehouse", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Car cars;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String location;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "warehouse_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Warehouse warehouse;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("make")
    private String mark;
    private String model;
    @JsonProperty("year_model")
    private int year;
    private double price;
    private boolean licensed;
    @JsonProperty("date_added")
    private Date dateAdded;
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Car car;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private float lat;
    @JsonProperty("long")
    private float lon;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "warehouse_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Warehouse warehouse;
}
```

After inserting data in H2 DB, I can see flowing tables and data.

[image]

Car:

[image]

Vehicle:

[image]

Location:

[image]

As you can see all data is fine except Location. It has missing warehouse_id. What did I miss? Also identical code and table relationship between warehouse and car one-to-one works fine. But for location it doesn't work. I have no idea what was missed.

Comment: How are you saving the data? Can you show the code?

Comment: @pringi thx  a lot! Your question help me to fix my issue. I posted the fixed saving code as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pringi for asking the question. After pringi's question I checked my saving method:-

```
    public Warehouse saveWareHouse(Warehouse warehouse) {
    Car car = warehouse.getCars();
    car.setWarehouse(warehouse);
    Location location = warehouse.getLocation(); // is added newly 
    location.setWarehouse(warehouse); // is added newly
    List<Vehicle> vehicles  = car.getVehicles();
    vehicles.forEach( vehicle -> {
        vehicle.setCar(car);
    });
    return warehouseRepository.save(warehouse);
}
```

After adding missing 2 line, it is fixed and working fine.

[image]